# Heroku deployment with Jekyll ([4] ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run)

Tags: heroku, deployment, jekyll

I do not understand how Jekyll/Heroku can come back with nothing to run - I followed the Jekyll Heroku instructions on the official Heroku docs ( I fixed a favicon error as well) and I just don't know what I'm missing at this point. I then configured the app for Puma & I can't seem to find the solution after checking other S/O posts and googling around.

```
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274627+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274648+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.11.3 (ruby 2.5.0-p0), codename: Love Song
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274650+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 32
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274652+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: development
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274654+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 3
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274655+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Phased restart available
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274663+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ERROR: No application configured, noth
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274627+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274648+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.11.3 (ruby 2.5.0-p0), codename: Love Song
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274650+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 32
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274652+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: development
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274654+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 3
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274655+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Phased restart available
2018-03-14T16:27:11.274663+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run
2018-03-14T16:27:11.635258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-14T16:27:13.137740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=the8-bitblog.herokuapp.com request_id=d5005423-9255-4d6d-983f-db1b80b5dca9 fwd="70.48.185.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-03-14T16:27:14.209900+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=the8-bitblog.herokuapp.com request_id=12876663-5bf2-483d-b87b-17c435ef9072 fwd="70.48.185.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=httpsing to run
2018-03-14T16:27:11.635258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-14T16:27:13.137740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=the8-bitblog.herokuapp.com request_id=d5005423-9255-4d6d-983f-db1b80b5dca9 fwd="70.48.185.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-03-14T16:27:14.209900+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=the8-bitblog.herokuapp.com request_id=12876663-5bf2-483d-b87b-17c435ef9072 fwd="70.48.185.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I recently deployed a rails app and was careful to put my Procfile & Rakefile in root / specify those params but for some reason, it won't start here. Is this an issue with having a free Heroku account (therefore limited workers?) I'm not entirely sure how that extends.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that's fixed but back to favicon errors ... 2018-03-

```
14T16:54:24.096956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=the8-bitblog.herokuapp.com request_id=b9345a18-bfb4-4f68-a310-e703f0aa1a3a fwd="70.48.185.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protoc
ol=https
2018-03-14T16:54:24.740532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=the8-bitblog.herokuapp.com request_id=d8418c31-c457-4b55-862b-9181162e8192 fwd="70.48.185.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```